# Github Actions for multi projects for same solution

Tags: github-actions

How does one go about triggering different workflows based on which branches the code changes are from?

i.e. consider the following:

```
MyCoolPackages.sln
  |__ PackageOne.csproj
  |__ PackageTwo.csproj
```

So my current workflow is set to build `PackageOne` every time there is a `PR` for `main/develop` branches. But lets say I've added a new feature to `PackageTwo` and only want that project to build and release. Can find examples for this type of GA. What are the approaches here? Have a generic workflow and pass in the solution name? But how to go about doing that based on code changes?

Comment: GitHub Actions has no native solution for this. You'd have to write your own (bash) script to detect changes and run tasks accordingly. Some tools (e.g. jest for javascript) support testing only changed files.

Comment: Thats a shame, as this is quite common solution structure :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to strap together a solution here => https://github.com/Syed-RI/the_bruno_project